# Jqueryui resizable. Cursor comes to foreground through other elements

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a container that is resizable. In this container I have a list in a div. The list is larger than the container so it goes outside. My problem is, when I hover an element of the list, if my cursor goes at the height of the container border, the cursor change and I am eable to resize the container.

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/9B3YZ/

The only thing done is a simple `$("#main").resizable({
    handles :'s'
});`

Just hover the different lines of the list to see the cursor change.

How is it possible ? My list is in a div with a specific z-index of '2' to be in the foreground. It's like the background container comes foreground trough my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an inline style `z-index:1000;` is being applied to `.ui-resizable-s`.

```
.divAmUl{
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100px;
    z-index:1001;  /* changed z-index */
    border:1px solid #a6c9e2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:white;
 }
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/9B3YZ/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

It's because the resizable jQuery UI handler set a `z-index` of 1000 on the element.

You can set an higher z-index like 2000:

```
 .divAmUl{
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100px;
    z-index:2000;
    border:1px solid #a6c9e2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:white;
 }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9B3YZ/3/

Comment: Damn same answer 30 sec later :-(

Comment: 2000 seems like overkill though

Comment: how, I understand you feeling Edward, Having the good solution 2 seconds late ^^, got a +1 too